# Python: defining a function with mean and standard deviation calculation

Tags: python, list, function, mean, standard-deviation

I am trying to calculate mean and the population standard deviation without using stats module...and my code will be

```
total = 0
sum3 = 0
def stats():
    global total
    for numbers in range(0,len(my_list)):
        total = total + my_list[numbers]
    mean = total / len(my_list)    
    print(mean)
    for numbers in range(0,len(my_list)):
        global sum3 
        sum3 = sum3 + (my_list[numbers] - mean)**2
        sum21 = sum3 / len(my_list)
    standard_dev = sum21**(1/2)
    print(standard_dev)
my_list1 = input()
my_list = my_list1.split()
print(my_list)
stats()
```

also help me to assign a list of numbers to int.....thank u

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. The stats methods have not been used here.

Only python methods have been used to speed up the functions.

```
def mean(my_list):
         sum = sum(my_list)
         return sum/len(my_list)

def standard_deviation(my_list):
         mean = mean(my_list)
         temp = 0
         for item in my_list:
                  temp = temp + ((item - mean) ** 2)
         return (temp/len(my_list))**0.5
```

Comment: Thanks brother.....but also can u tell me how to input a list and find it's sum...bcoz whenever I input a list it assigns itself to string.? Yr comments pls

Comment: Try using the map function like this:# number of elements 

`n = int(input("Enter number of elements : ")) 
  
a = list(map(int,input("\nEnter the numbers : ").strip().split()))[:n] 
  
print("\nList is - ", a) `

Comment: Sorry for the improper indentation, the code block is not indenting properly in the comments. The code in the comment has 3 lines,
First one starts from `n = int`
Next one starts at `a = list`
Last one starts at `print("List`

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a nice place to use list comprehension for brevity's sake.

```py
def mean(l):
    return sum(l) / len(l)

def stdev(l):
    # Get the mean of the list
    m = mean(l)
    # Subtract the mean from each item and square the result
    # Take the mean from the resulting list
    m_of_sqrd = mean([(i-m)**2 for i in l])
    # Return the root 
    return m_of_sqrd ** 0.5

inp = input()
values = [int(item) for item in inp.split()]

print(mean(values))
print(stdev(values))
```